# Extract strings of length 32 characters

Tags: regex, vba

I'm parsing an email body to extract strings of length 32 characters (MD5 hashes). I'm getting matches on strings of more than 32 characters as well and I can't tweak the regex to get it working.

```
Sub GetValueUsingRegEx()

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Reg1 As RegExp
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match
    Dim pat As String

    Set olMail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)
    'Debug.Print olMail.Body

    pat = "[a-fA-F0-9]{32}"
    Call parseTheEmail(pat, olMail)

End Sub

Sub parseTheEmail(ByVal pat As String, ByVal email As Outlook.MailItem)
    Set Reg1 = New RegExp
    With Reg1
        .pattern = pat
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With
    If Reg1.Test(email.Body) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(email.Body)
        For Each M In M1
            Debug.Print M
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Add start of string `^` and end of string `$` to your regex pattern.  The way you have it now is just looking for groups of 32 characters that match the pattern.

Comment: @Dave `^` and `$` are line start/end anchors - which is fine if it's on a line by itself. This sounds like it needs word boundaries `\b` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a word boundary:

```
pat = "\b[a-fA-F0-9]{32}\b"
```

or if it appears on a separate line by itself then you can use:

```
pat = "^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$"
```

and set the regex `.MultiLine` property to `True`